# Retrieve and store API details in the cache

Tags: android

I have an android app with login and registration which uses an api to get the login details. I want to store the api details in cache of android phone as the api automatically logs out from the server after a certain minute. So that this information can be retrieved and the app auto logs in whenever the app is started next time and the user does not have to type user and password. Also when the user clicks logout button, the whole cache is cleared. How can i implement this? Please help.

Comment: Have you tried with `sharedPreference` in android ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [account manager api](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html). It is the recommended way to store and authenticate user’s credentials. Here is a gist of how it works.

[image: Graph]

You can find a full example [here](https://www.pilanites.com/android-account-manager/)